# DotNet HighCharts , Populates a pie with the result of a query

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, highcharts

I need to populate a pie with data which are the result of a query (LINQ To SQL)

The problem is i cannot manage to add a foreach inside this code to insert my data instead of the static Firefox,Chrome,IE ect ...

```
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //RepeaterVersionsForPie.DataSource = DAaccess.LibDataVersion.LibDataVersion.GetNumberOfCompaniesUsingEachVersions();
            //RepeaterVersionsForPie.DataBind();

            var test = DAaccess.LibDataVersion.LibDataVersion.GetNumberOfCompaniesUsingEachVersions();

            Highcharts chart = new Highcharts("chart")
.InitChart(new Chart { PlotShadow = false })
.SetTitle(new Title { Text = "Browser market shares at a specific website, 2010" })
.SetTooltip(new Tooltip { Formatter = "function() { return '<b>'+ this.point.name +'</b>: '+ this.percentage +' %'; }" })
.SetPlotOptions(new PlotOptions
{
    Pie = new PlotOptionsPie
    {
        AllowPointSelect = true,
        Cursor = Cursors.Pointer,
        DataLabels = new PlotOptionsPieDataLabels
        {
            Color = ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#000000"),
            ConnectorColor = ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#000000"),
            Formatter = "function() { return '<b>'+ this.point.name +'</b>: '+ this.percentage +' %'; }"
        },
        Point = new PlotOptionsPiePoint
        {
            Events = new PlotOptionsPiePointEvents
            {
                Click = "function() { alert (this.category +': '+ this.y); }"

            }
        }

    }
})
.SetSeries(new Series
{
    Type = ChartTypes.Pie,
    Name = "Browser share",
    Data = new Data(new object[]
                                           {
                                               new object[] { "Firefox", 45.0 },
                                               new object[] { "IE", 26.8 },
                                               new DotNet.Highcharts.Options.Point
                                               {
                                                   Name = "Chrome",
                                                   Y = 12.8,
                                                   Sliced = true,
                                                   Selected = true
                                               },
                                               new object[] { "Safari", 8.5 },
                                               new object[] { "Opera", 6.2 },
                                               new object[] { "Others", 0.7 }
                                           })
});
            ltrChart.Text = chart.ToHtmlString();







        }
```

Actually , i need to be able to insert something like this:

```
foreach ( var item in test )
{
new object[] { item.name, item.count}
}
```

But VS doesn't allow me to do such thing 
Thanks in advance for your help ...

Answer (score 3):

You could create an extension method for whatever type `DAaccess.LibDataVersion.LibDataVersion.GetNumberOfCompaniesUsingEachVersions()` returns and have it return the results in the Pie-shaped Series format.

```
public static class DotNetHighChartsExtensions
{
    public static object[] ToPieChartSeries(this WhateverThatTypeIs data)
    {
        var returnObject = new List<object>();

        foreach ( var item in data )
        {
            returnObject.Add(new object[] { item.name, item.count});
        }

        return returnObject.ToArray();
    }
}
```

Then in your code where you have your static code, you'd just replace it with:

```
Data = new Data(test.ToPieChartSeries())
```

Alternatively, you could have the `ToPieChartSeries` method return the `Data` object that is being sought for by the `Series` object.

While I haven't worked with this DotNet.HighCharts project, I have worked with and built my own HighCharts objects for a couple of MVC projects. On the face of it, it looks like this are ultimately doing the same thing I did: Create a .NET object that could be serialized as JSON and recognized by the HighCharts javascript library.

Comment: Hey, your solution lead me to solve my problem.  I had to modify it slightly and I got it working.  Thanks for the help.  I would give you the bounty, but I set it on someone elses question.  Hopefully it works for them and they mark it as accepted.

Comment: I see now how to award the bounty, but I have to wait 24 hours.

Comment: See my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10074620/pass-a-list-of-series-to-setseries/10096108#10096108. As I noted, I am not familiar with the DotNet.HighCharts project, but based on Linger's comments, the method may need to return as an array of Series instead of an array of object.

Answer (score 2):

```
SetSeries(new Series {
                Type = ChartTypes.Pie,
                Data = new Data(test.Select(d => new { Name = d.name, Y = d.count }).ToArray())
            })
```