# Pass a List of Series to SetSeries

Tags: visual-studio-2010, highcharts

I am using DotNet.Highcharts in conjunction with Visual Studio 2010.  I have created an array of Series:

```
List<Series> allSeries = new List<Series>();
```

I then looped through a database and added several different Series.  Then I created a Highchart and need to add the allSeries list to it.  I have the code below that I used to create a Series one at a time.  How can I take the allSeries list and pass it to SetSeries?

```
.SetSeries(new[]
           {
               new Series { Name = "Combiner 2", Data = new Data(myData2) },
               new Series { Name = "Combiner 3", Data = new Data(myData3) }
           });
```

Comment: If I may ask how you got your series into the List of series? I am fighting that battle right now.

Comment: That is outside the scope of this question.  However, if you create a new question I will respond to it.  I just don't want to add it above and can't add the code here as a comment.

Comment: No worries. I actually just solved it. Problem was syntax going from C# coded examples to VB.NET which is what we use in-house. Upvoted this question because it helped solve another issue we had.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if I am left to assume that the `myData2` and `myData3` objects are contained in or could be extracted from `allSeries`, then you should be able to do something like this:

```
.SetSeries(allSeries.Select(s=> new Series { Name = s.Name, Data = s.Data }));
```

EDIT:
If set series isn't looking for an `IEnumerable<Series>` but instead needs `Object[]` or `Series[]`, then you could do this:

```
//casts series elements to object, then projects to array
.SetSeries(allSeries.Select(s=> (object)new Series { Name = s.Name, Data = s.Data }).ToArray());
```

or maybe this:

```
//projects series elements to array of series
.SetSeries(allSeries.Select(s=> new Series { Name = s.Name, Data = s.Data }).ToArray());
```

it all depends on what the method signature for `SetSeries` is.

Comment: Yes you are correct.  The myData2 and myData3 would no longer be needed because they would be a part of allSeries along with other Series.  The suggested code as you have produces an error.  I get the error message **Unknown method 'SetSeries(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<DotNet.Highcharts.Options.Series>)' of 'DotNet.Highcharts.Highcharts'**

Comment: I was basing my response on the guess that .SetSeries was a method expecting an IEnumerable<Series>. I'll edit my answer to see if that helps.

Comment: Tried it out and got it working.  The third option is what I needed.  The **projects series elements to array of series** is what worked for me.