# DotNet.HighCharts - PieChart by populating data by code

Tags: c#, highcharts, dotnethighcharts

I'm looking at DotNet.HighCharts and just starting to try to understand it. 
I was thinking of doing something more "simple" just to get the hang of it like the pie chart.

I looked at the following link [DotNet HighCharts , Populates a pie with the result of a query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9226560/dotnet-highcharts-populates-a-pie-with-the-result-of-a-query)  and wanted to try to populate the data from code behind.  I wanted to dumb-it-down a lot just so i can learn and understand it. Learn how to crawl first before i learn to run with it and populate from the database.

I'm thinking that I'm not understanding how to set up the series data correctly.
This is how I'm populating a series object:

```
  var browers = new List<object[]>();
  browers.Add(new object[] { "Firefox", 35.0 });
  browers.Add(new object[] { "IE", 25 });
  browers.Add(new object[] { "Safari", 20 });
  browers.Add(new object[] { "Opera", 15 });
  browers.Add(new object[] { "Others", 5 });

  List<Series> browserSeries = new List<Series>();

  //I think this is causing the problem
  browserSeries.Add(new Series
  {
        Name = "Browsers",
        Data = new Data(browers.ToArray())
  });
```

And then it is done here just like the link:

```
    .SetSeries(new Series
           {
               Type = ChartTypes.Pie,
               Name = "Browser share",
               Data = new Data(browserSeries.Select(b => new { Name = b.Name, Y = b.Data }).ToArray())
           });
```

Currently the chart does not display any data.  It's just blank. 
Can someone point me in the right direction of what i've done wrong?

Thanks a lot for the help.

Comment: Do you receive any errors? How your data looks like after parsing? I mena in javascript? (you can use console.log(data) in JS)

Comment: Hi Sebastian, 
Thanks for your suggestion to use console.log 
I didn't even think about that. 
There is data but it is messed up. Here is a screenshot of it: http://tinypic.com/r/346ozti/5

So I definitely did not set up the array correctly. It's pretty obvious from the screenshot. I think it's because I do "ToArray()" twice when i should only be doing it once.
I'll keep plugging away at it.
tHanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I broke it down and tried to understand what I was doing wrong. 
For a pie chart I didn't need a series. 
So basically when the list of objects was created I just needed to set the data to that list like:

```
.SetSeries(new Series
 {
    Type = ChartTypes.Pie,
    Name = "Browser share",
    Data = new Data(browsers.ToArray())
 });
```

And the pie chart appeared perfectly. 
Yes, I made a spelling mistake with "browers" ... but at least the pie chart is showing up now :)

Answer (score 0):

```
.SetSeries(new Series
         {
            Type = ChartTypes.Pie,
            Name = "Browser share",
            Data = new Data(new object[] { browers.Select(b => new {Name =b.GetValue(0), Y = b.GetValue(1) }).ToArray() })
         });
```

Hi, This code has worked for me.

Comment: 'ltrPiechart.Text = (chart2.ToHtmlString().Replace("[[","[")).Replace("]]","]");